# Inconsistent accessibility: field type ... is less accessible than field

Tags: c#

I already read about that i change every protected or private for public and still nothing.

I dont know which part is wrong. I want to add list of objects Film.

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Programowanie_WypozyczalniaFilmow.Film>' is less accessible than field 'Programowanie_WypozyczalniaFilmow.Katalog.listaFilmow'
```

---

```
    namespace Programowanie_WypozyczalniaFilmow
 {
public partial class Katalog : Form
{
   public Katalog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   public List<Film> listaFilmow = new List<Film>();
```

but Filmy looks like this:

```
namespace Programowanie_WypozyczalniaFilmow
{
class Film
{
    public string tytul, rezyser, gatunek, nosnik;//protected
    public int rokProdukcji, kategoriaCenowa;//protected
    public double cena;//protected
    public bool czyDostepna;//protected
    public int IDFilmu;
    public double cenaNajwyzsza = 15.99, cenaSrednia=10.00, cenaNiska=5.00;


    public Film(string tytul, string rezyser, string gatunek, string nosnik,          int rokProdukcji,int kategoriaCenowa , int idFilmu)
    {
        this.tytul = tytul;
        this.rezyser = rezyser;
        this.gatunek = gatunek;
        this.nosnik = nosnik;
        this.rokProdukcji = rokProdukcji;
        this.kategoriaCenowa = kategoriaCenowa;
        cena = jakaCena(kategoriaCenowa);
        this.IDFilmu = idFilmu;

    }
```

Comment: It dont work  I dont know why.

Comment: Ask another question

Comment: It is now: "public class Film" but it still dont work

Comment: People will be happy to help you, ask another question.

Comment: Ah, ok. srr now i know what you mean. Ok.